# Android - showing events nearby to user

Tags: php, android, mysql, location

I will take events from some websites. Then will record them to database and show the user when runs the app according to her location.

1. Using `wamp` `sql` database is an old and deprecated way? Like this
   http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/
   I will only record event names, location.
2. Should i use a database, right? I will record longitude and latitude. When user runs app, i only retrieve the events according to her locations? For example +100 - 100 meters to the location, calculating longitude latitude.
3. I am parsing the information from websites. I already did this in `java` eclipse. I used `Phantomjs` and `jsoup`. So, can i migrate them to android without changing or do you suggest anything different?

I really searched those questions but could not find such satisfying answers.

Comment: i am really confused about what i should use. jsoup okhtto seleniumwebdriver or even if i need webdriver or a server

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no need to use database. You could just get the location of the device. Make a http query to your website. Parse the data by using some method and then you could show to the users.

For parsing i always use OKHTTP with jackson for parsing json data. It will be very convenient assuming your response data will be in json.

Comment: But events are from different websites, from university websites. universities has different campus at different locations. You mean after i take location, i should search all event websites? It sounds good actually. And i dont have a website.

Comment: Yeah when users open up your app. You could just search all event in your university website. It could be dynamic. Bcoz the events wont be permanent right. But if you want you could use inbuilt sqlite database for caching purposes

Comment: But not only a website. 4 websites. In java, taking all events took 1.5 minutes and then filtering by location, it will last around 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jsoup in android. But not phantomjs.

Comment: Jsoup couldnot load the all elements of a website that contains high javascript. So, i used phantomjs.

Comment: You can build a server which collects all information required and build an api for android which requests events. So from android, call api, your server will get events and parse them using jsoup and phantomjs. And return it to android. This should not need database unless you want to reuse the events.

Comment: Probably i wont reuse events.You meant JSP java server pages?

Comment: Can you give example please? I could not understand. Inside server, can i use phantomjs?

Comment: I can not give you example of server. If i were you, i would build server in php and try to see if i can use phantomjs in php server.

Comment: For example apache wamp server?

Comment: Build a live server with backend and front end  i mean.